# Order by time for sysdate

Tags: javascript, oracle, extjs, sysdate

I have date displayed like that :

[image: date]

So here is how it works, an user fills a form, when he cliks on submit button, I save the datas in my db with a procedure, and I add sysdate in order to make an id for each form submitted. So I make an INSERT TO, with DATE_ID = sysdate. Then I show all the form submitted on an admin page. I want to display time with date provided by sysdate so I make the TO_CHAR. One group of item = One submit.

Here is how I show sysdate :

```
select to_char(DATE_ID, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as DATE_ID
```

and order it with

```
ORDER BY DATE_ID DESC;
```

How can I order date with the time?

Comment: The problem seems to be that you change meaning for `DATE_ID`. Perhaps `select to_char(DATE_ID, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as DATE_ID, DATE_ID AS DUMMY ... ORDER BY DUMMY DESC`?

Comment: I wrote that, that's not working

Comment: Within a single day what you're doing should work; if the data splits over days (particularly over months) then Joachim's approach would be safer. So, what are you doing with the results of the query - is your application reordering them before display? It seems to be generating the per-second intervals and is maybe ordering those intervals itself? (Not sure what this has to do with `sysdate`).

Comment: @AlexPoole  My application is a form, when an user submit the form, I catch the date+time of the submit with sysdate. Problem is that sysdate doesn't show the time. For each group of items, a submit has been made (when there are 2 items, the items was sending at the same time with ONE click on submit). So to rearrange that in the admin page, I add the time with to_char. I want to show newer submit first

Comment: OK, but how does the form translate the results of your query into what's actually displayed, with the groups of items, and the groups themselves ordered by date/time? It seems like there must be something in the form that is rearranging things and ignoring the order the data was returned (by the `order by` clause). You could tell if that's the case by ordering by something different in the query and seeing if it affects the display order.

Comment: @So4ne I think you'll need to add some sample data and a sample query to show what datatypes and query is involved. It feels that I'm missing something when reading your description.

Comment: @AlexPoole The groups are pure javascript, the date of groups is shown by DATE_ID like the items "groupTextTpl: '{[values.rs[0].data.DATE_ID]} ({[values.rs.length]} {[values.rs.length > 1 ? "Items" : "Item"]})'" where DATE_ID is an index in order to recording to db. I don't think it can block the order by

Comment: @So4ne - 'the date of groups is shown by DATE_ID' - `DATE_ID` is the string representation; from that it sounds like JS is ordering by that, in ascending order? I think you need to add your JS to the question, particularly how `values` is populated and manipulated.

Comment: @AlexPoole Ok I add JS, but by using this framework for long time, don't think it comes from that.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson update is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean is to sort by the stored date/time values not as the converted character values, so just prefix the column with the table alias in the ORDER BY:

```
SELECT to_char(DATE_ID, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as DATE_ID
FROM some_table tbl
ORDER BY tbl.DATE_ID DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an alias name that does not equal the actual column name. Then your code should work.